# Incorrect new Uri (base, relative)

Tags: c#, uri

I am working on generic webshops scraper and came across strange problem. Actually, I required correct URL's for all the products listed on the webpage. Most of the time those products href's are relative.

I am using new Uri method to create complete product URL.

```
new Uri (base, href) 

//this actually decide to add "/" before product href

href = x.ProductHref.IsUrlAbsolute() ? x.ProductHref : ((x.ProductHref.StartsWith("/") || (x.ProductHref.StartsWith("."))) ? x.ProductHref : "/" + x.ProductHref)
```

Failed result:How to  correct this

```
Base URL: "www.bebitalia.it/Products/ProductList_it.html#filter&.CHAISE_LONGUE"
Product href: Product-landscape-chaise_longue_118_it.html
Result : http://www.bebitalia.it/Product-landscape-chaise_longue_118_it.html ==> Status Wrong
Expected:  http://www.bebitalia.it/Products/Product-landscape-chaise_longue_118_it.html
```

I tried to correct it but then it does not work for others :). Want to make it generic. Please suggest any solution, AM I in right direction or better approach is required.

Comment: Surely it's just  : "/Products/" + x.ProductHref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folks I solved it.Now it is generic and working for all scenarios.

PageURL is base url

href = (x.ProductHref.IsUrlAbsolute() || (!x.ProductHref.Contains("/") && !PageUrl.AbsoluteUri.EndsWith("/"))
                    ?
                    x.ProductHref : (
                    (x.ProductHref.StartsWith("/") || (x.ProductHref.StartsWith(".")))
                    ? x.ProductHref : "/" + x.ProductHref))

Url = new Uri(PageUrl, href)

I extracted a rule =>if base url does not end with "/" and productURL(relative) also does not contain "/" Whereas base is absolute then never add "/" to relative.

I do not know how browser automatically resolve this type of scenarios.
 it must be resolved automatically
 when creating new uri (base,relative).

Answer (score 0):

Any link that starts with a `/` is treated as being in the root of the domain.  So first, I'll reformat your code for clarity:

```
href = x.ProductHref.IsUrlAbsolute() 
       ? x.ProductHref 
       : (x.ProductHref.StartsWith("/") || (x.ProductHref.StartsWith("."))
            ? x.ProductHref 
            : "/" + x.ProductHref;
```

Reducing this to how it evaluates:

```
href = false 
       ? // Nothing 
       : (false || false)
            ? // Nothing 
            : "/" + "Product-landscape-chaise_longue_118_it.html";
```

That produces the URL `/Product-landscape-chaise_longue_118_it.html`, which starts with a `/` and so is in the root of your domain.

How you fix this is entirely determined by the rest of your code, which you didn't provide, so I can't offer any suggestions.

Comment: my solution was not generic in fact thats why I have not provided it. its failed  for following then; Base URl= http://caliroots.com/sfd/
Product href: ./product.asp?id=42952
Result: http://caliroots.com/sfd/product.asp?id=42952  Status OK

Comment: Base URL: http://shop.mango.com/DK/mango/new
Product href:
DK/p0/mango/new/chiffon-baby-doll-dress/?id=83439925_OW&n=1&s=nuevo&ie=0&m=&ts=1371208214121
Result: http://shop.mango.com/DK/p0/mango/new/chiffon-baby-doll-dress/?id=83439925_OW&n=1&s=nuevo&ie=0&m=&ts=1371208214121   Status OK
Base URL:http://www.zalando.it/scarpe-con-tacco/
Product href: oxitaly-decollete-nero-ox211a01d-802.html
Result: http://www.zalando.it/oxitaly-decollete-nero-ox211a01d-802.html  Status  OK

Comment: @JehangirHaider - Your problem is bad data, then. [GIGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).  You need to establish a convention: "If you start the product href with a `/`, it does this. If you start with a `./` it does *this*.  And if you don't put in either, it does this other thing."  Then you code for that convention.

Answer (score 0):

You should know if you change `href` after new Uri(), it won't change the result, but I think it was before You called the constructor.

What is base? `www.bebitalia.it/Products/ProductList_it.html#filter&.CHAISE_LONGUE` is not a valid `Uri` and `Uri` has no constructor with 2 string parameter.

If href is absolute, the constructor `new Uri(Uri,String)` will handle it automatically, and places the `/` too. It will also cut off everything from the base Uri after the TLD(and probably this is what happened in your code).

[HERE](http://ideone.com/lWsaO7) You can see how it works (it is the MSDN sample)

Comment: www.bebitalia.it/Products/ProductList_it.html#filter&.CHAISE_LONGUE is base URI